# Hyper-V installation components are going to be reversed in Windows 10 pro

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I went to the following path in order to try to enable Hyper V on Windows 10 Pro:

> **Control Panel** > **All Control Panel Items** > **Programs and Features**
>   **Installed Updates** > **Turn Windows features on or off**

I activated all the check boxes related to Hyper-V and then I rebooted the computer.

During the installation of the hyper-V components Windows said that there was a problem and all the changes made until that moment should be reversed!

Previously I went under the BIOS/UEFI and I activated the “Intel VT-x,” “Intel Virtualization Technology”, “Virtualization Extensions" or something similar. And when I run the command `systeminfo.exe` this is what I see :

```
Host Name:                 DESKTOP
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.15063 N/A Build 15063
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Io
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                
Original Install Date:     6/30/2017, 3:54:03 PM
System Boot Time:          9/12/2017, 10:27:37 AM
System Manufacturer:       Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model:              Z87-HD3
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~3400 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. F7, 1/20/2014
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              it;Italian (Italy)
Time Zone:                 (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna
Total Physical Memory:     8,066 MB
Available Physical Memory: 4,379 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  9,346 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 5,603 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    3,743 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\DESKTOP-Q69U65N
Hotfix(s):                 3 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4022405
                           [02]: KB4034662
                           [03]: KB4034674
Network Card(s):           2 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [02]: TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Wi-Fi
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     192.168.1.1
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 192.168.1.3
                                 [02]:

Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

What now? I have all the necessary features to make it work. Can someone help me to find where could be the error?

maybe this could be also interesting :

[image: log pic]

and this :

[image: this]

Comment: Please don't post command prompt outputs as images. They are unclear, can't be adjusted for readability, hard to index for search engines and unreadable for people using screen readers. Just copy and paste the text, then select it and press `Ctrl`+`K` to apply correct formatting.

Comment: Can you run a VM? Do you see the HyperV (virtmgmt.msc) shortcut in start menu?

Comment: There likely is a log file that was created which indicates the exact reason the Hyper-V feature wasn't able to be enabled.  Without specifics on the reason it wasn't enabled this question will be nearly impossible to answer.

Comment: "Intel64 Family 6 model 60 stepping 3 GenuineIntel 3400 Mhz" - This doesn't tell us what CPU you have.  "Physic memory = 8.066 MB" - I hope you have more then 8 MB of physical memory.  You should update your question with accurate information because you don't have 8 MB of physical memory installed.

Comment: No,I don't see any virtmgmt.msc in the start menu ; where I can find the log file ? CPU = Intel Core I5-4670K @ 3.40Ghz ; installed memory = 8 GB (7,88 GB available shown on the control panel)

Comment: Update your question with the accurate information.  Your question still indicates you have 4.533 MB free which does not make sense.  Please provide the exact, error you have received, in English.  Any event the log you are looking for, and still have not supplied to us, is CSB.log. Be sure you provide any English translations for us.

Comment: Open the  PowerShell window, copy and paste the command below, press Enter,                                                                                                                      *Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All*

Comment: yeah. I tried to install the hyper-v components trying for the second time. This time I've been able to do it,maybe because I've changed the language,from italian to english ? Because this is the only change that I made from last time. And then I activated the hyper-v with the command of vembutech.

Comment: solution : bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

Comment: @Ramhound : I found that the file you are talking about is called "CBS.log",not "CSB.log".

Comment: I made a Typo......